# Dockerfile expose port for node.js image

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to expose port for `node.js` image but it's doesn't expose the port outside :

```
FROM node:4-onbuild
ADD . /opt/app

EXPOSE 8000:8000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

only when I declare the port when running the image it's works

```
docker run -p=8000:8000 node
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `EXPOSE` directive is **metadata** only. If you check:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

You'll see you still need to manually expose the port. The `EXPOSE` directive is useful for platforms which might want to know what a container expects to expose. For example, on OpenShift if I deployed your container it would suggest I expose port 8000.

If you don't want to manually expose the port, try this:

```
docker run --net=host
```

This will bind the container network controller to the host network . Be aware however this is a security concern, as there is no isolation between the container and the host machine (for TCPIP or UDP). This means your container can try to listen to *any* port on the host! Some containers do run like this, for example the consul client:

https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/

Which is a chatty client which talks over lots of ports. Binding it to the host makes it much easier to quickly run the client, but I would avoid that approach unless absolutely necessary. Unfortunately, you'll probably just need to get used to the `-p` flag!